# Can not get my data to render from mlab. my db is connected but but my ejs template is not working

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>MY APP</title>
</head>
<body>
May Node and Express be with you.

<ul class="logins">
&lt; for(const i=0; i &lt;login.length; i++) { &gt;
<li class="login">
<span>&lt; login[i].firstName &gt;</span>
<span>&lt; login[i].age &gt;</span>
</li>
&lt; } &gt;
</ul>

<form action="/login" method="POST">
<input type="text" placeholder="First Name" 
name="firstName">
<input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" 
name="lastName">
<input type="text" placeholder="Age" name="age">
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

My HTML form is the same, it just doesnt have the ejs template. Here is my code for the ejs template:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {           
db.collection('login').find().toArray((err, result)=> 
{ if (err) return console.log(err)
// renders index.ejs
res.render('index.ejs', {login: result})
})
})
```

not sure if im rendering my template the wrong way or if im even witing the code the right way.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?  Please be more explicit.  What is the problem with the result?

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul class="logins">
&lt; login.forEach(data) { &gt;
<li class="login">
<span>&lt; data.firstName &gt;</span>
<span>&lt; data.age &gt;</span>
</li>
&lt; } &gt;
</ul>
```

Or

```
<ul class="logins">
&lt; for(const i=0; i &lt;login.length; i++) { &gt;
<li class="login">
<span>&lt; login.firstName &gt;</span>
<span>&lt; login.age &gt;</span>
</li>
&lt; } &gt;
</ul>
```

I think 'login' is an object. toArray method may not be working.
So, please that code and if you have an error let me know.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you use < > do display your variable and to evaluate your code. To display you have to use <%- %> or <%= %>. To evaluate your for you have to use <% %>

The correct code is the following :

```
<ul class="logins">
<% for(const i=0; i &lt;login.length; i++) { %>
    <li class="login">
        <span><%- login[i].firstName %></span>
        <span><%- login[i].age %></span>
    </li>
<% } %>
</ul>
```